# azure local storage account name

Tags: azure, storage, local, explorer

we created a local storage account through  the azure portal -> add iot edge module -> Container create options:

```
     "Env":[
       "LOCAL_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=pippo",
       "LOCALSTORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY=some key"
     ],
```

Next we connect to the local storage using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. When we input the connection string, we can use whatever account name and not the one specified in the LOCAL_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME as expected.
Is it a normal behaviour ?

best regards

Filippo

Comment: What do you mean by local storage account? there isn't any "local" storage account in azure resources.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-blob?view=iotedge-2018-06